# Show invisible rows which aren't hidden

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that has a bunch of 'hidden' rows. Except unhiding rows does not reveal them.

I can pull the rows out one at a time.

[image]

And pull them down:

[image]

But unhiding does nothing:

[image]

How do I reveal the remaining rows?

Comment: Change the row height?

Comment: or they may be "hidden" because of a filter?

Comment: Grab the separator carefully and drag down to exposes the row(s).  Columns work the same way.

Comment: It's 100% because of a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, ensure that no filter is applied to the spreadsheet
- After that, if `Unhide` does not work, chances are the invisible rows are just set to a very small size (e.g. 1 pixel each), in which case you need to select the first visible row, down to the next visible row (i.e. include all invisible rows in your selection), select `Row Height` and set an appropriate size manually

Comment: A filter is definitely applied in the sample images. That's what the blue row numbers means.

Comment: @AlexM I have a strange instance in a workbook where I have blue numbers on a table, where I have cleared the filter off and they still remain blue, might post as a question Monday

Comment: @PeterH I would love to have a crack at that one